# how to handle localization in DatePickerDialog - Android?

Tags: android

[image]

My app supports Chinese and English languages. Where English works fine, issue is only with Chinese. When I open DatePickerDialog by default there are some fields on popup are loading in Chinese but as you can see in screenshot "Mon, Jan 15" is not in Chinese. Since this is default popup and I have not set any Chinese text to DatePickerDialog this dialog.

My question is

1. How I can change "Mon, Jan 15" to Chinese
2. Why "Mon, Jan 15" not changed to Chinese by default?

Here is my code:

```
datePickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showDialog(0);
    }
});

@Override
@Deprecated
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month, day);
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                      int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
    day = selectedDay;
    month = selectedMonth;
    year = selectedYear;
    datePickerButton.setText(selectedDay + " / " + (selectedMonth + 1) + " / "
            + selectedYear);
}
};
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you share your code and xml layout?

Comment: @propoLis i have added my code snippet above. Its system popup I am opening and not custom

Comment: In your shoes I woulnd bother about this ... seems this is a default way of showing date on android so Chinese people used to it already ...

Comment: @Selvin you mean to say "Mon, Jan 15" in this case will ways be like this? if only my app language is Chinese?